# htaccess: redirect images to a page that shows the images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all images to a showimage.php, using htaccess

But if I try something like

```
RewriteRule ^images/([A-Za-z1-9]+).png$ showimage.php?image=$1 [L]
```

the image to be shown on that page will get redirected too (doh)

How to redirect all images, but **not** if they are requested from showimage.php? (or from this server)

Comment: So, what you mean is that showimage.php script does some sort of http get to the local (or remote) apache server to serve images?

Comment: Yes. showimage.php takes $_GET['image'] and serves that image

Comment: How do you precisely get the image content ? Does showimage.php do a cURL request for example, to the Apache server ?

Comment: No it's just <img src="xxx.jpg" />

Comment: Instead of htaccess maybe I should look into serving the images with readfile or curl something. But I would prefer not to

Comment: Ahhhhh.... ok, did not understand that at all... so you definitely have to check with the REFERER, since the source of the HTTP access will always be the browsing user's one. Don't have my box here, but try displaying the referer header in the access log as I explained, and check this value when you have the second GET for the image from showimage.php. It should display the value you have to filter

Comment: I see no referer header in the access log. It's too confusing, I give up. But thanx for the help

Comment: Did you restart Apache? Anyway, I've updated my solution, and had it work on my Apache build. The problem was the RewriteCond.

Comment: I can't get it to work no matter what I try :( You had it work so any image is redirected to a php file where the image is shown? It has to work 2 ways: redirect images. but dont redirect images requested by showimage.php (or this server)

Comment: This triggers redirect for ALL images everywhere on the server (also where it shouldnt): RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} myserver.test [NC]     RewriteRule ^images/(.*).jpg$ showimage.php?do=$1 [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1- no redirect if the query comes from the server
You just have to add a RewriteCond directive before the RewriteRule, which says that the following RewriteRule is not to be done if the source of the http query is this server.

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1
```

Depending on how your script does the get, you may need to use instead your server's private IP. Or add another RewriteCond with this IP, to prevent both to be redirected.

2- you can also prevent redirect depending on the referer of the query, but you have to be sure that it is sent with the query. (referer is the source URL that requested your URL. For example, if you're on http://localhost/index.php and click a link to http://localhost/help.php, the referer of the last one will be http://localhost/index.php).
You still use a RewriteCond, but with HTTP_REFERER instead of REMOTEHOST.

eg:

<del>RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !showimage.php</del>

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/images/.*\.png
```

You may have to toy a bit with the full referer, not user if this is enough, but just the idea to start with.
You can check which referer you have in the access log (if you have %{Referer}i enabled in the LogFormat you use)

Got it : problem was that, the REFERER is the URL that was asked, and not the rewritten one (should I've thought about it, it's obvious). So, the problem is that when you require http://localhost/images/x.png, it is rewritten as http://localhost/showimage.php?image=x.png which serves the page with the  inside. BUT the referer is NOT showimage.php but .../images/x.png (the initial URL). So, the RewriteCond on the HTTP_REFERER must check that the origin URL is something like /images/*.png instead.

Here is my working example. Rules are in [DOCROOT]/.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/images/.*\.png
RewriteRule ^images/([A-Za-z1-9-]+).png$ image.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Here is my image.php file:

```
<html>
Here it is : <img src="/images/<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>.png"/>
</html>
```

With my browser, calling http://[server ip]/images/foo.png will display an html page, containing the words "Here it is : " AND the requested picture, taken from [DOCROOT]/images/foo.png.

For the "not from this server" to work, you just add the previous RewriteCond about REMOTE_ADDR before the RewriteRule (when you don't specify [OR], they work as AND conditions - the rewriterule is triggered only if both conditions are true - not from this server and not from the php script)

Comment: I have tested around with it some. RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !127.0.0.1 changes nothing. If I try with RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 127.0.0.1 all images are redirected including the one on showimage.php. The latter is the same with RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !showimage.php.

Comment: Should'nt REMOTE_HOST be REMOTE_ADDR ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, REMOTE_ADDR is the correct one. On my box it's working with REMOTE_HOST (since I don't reverse-DNS the incoming IP, which is the standard in many Apache installations), but will break on other configurations. I change the answer

Comment: I went back to http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/smarter-way-to-prevent-image-hotlinking-with-htaccess/ Trying to get it to work, but simply can't, same as with your variation

Comment: Can you run a phpinfo() in one of your php script, and check the "REMOTE_ADDR" value in the "Apache Environment" section ? Maybe you've got a different source IP than 127.0.0.1 like, like I said, one of your server's addresses? And if your server is in IPv6,  you will have a different value for localhost than 127.0.0.1 (like 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 or  ::1)

Comment: Ok, I tried checking with phpinfo(), and it reads remote_addr as 127.0.0.1. It seems like the raw image itself also has the REMOTE_ADDR of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Could it be because I'm testing on a local apache server on windows maybe?

Comment: I'm so stupid. I overlooked/forgot that on showimage.php I check $_GET['image'] for the image ID (to retrieve image name in db) not the image name itself. Doh. So I think it will work after some fiddling around. Wow this was frustrating.. Thanx for your help ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Your problem gave me a hard time and made me learn interesting things!