# htaccess: Redirect images to a page but not load the image on the page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect with htaccess images url in a folder to a page that I'm showing, because I want to share that image on facebook (with share button of facebook and I put the image url. But when someone click on it in facebook it loads the image url And I want to redirect to the page that its showing).

I tried with this code:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*).(jpg|png|gif)$ http://www.somesitesample.com/page.php?$1 [L]
```

But in the page.php that is showing the image, don't load the images.
also tried this [[htaccess: redirect images to a page that shows the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028016/htaccess-redirect-images-to-a-page-that-shows-the-images/10028506#10028506][1])
but not success

Comment: what url do you use to display images on page.php?

Comment: to a subdirectory "uploads" with database: <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row_REC_photos['photo']; ?>">